# z-index não altera!

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o site: [Gás Muriaé](http://gasmuriae.com.br/), e um erro de z-index (provavelmente) que não consigo tirar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, o a banner está sobrepondo à barra de pedidos lateral.

Localmente, já alterei no css do plugin o z-index para um valor menor que z-index do banner mas não resolveu!

Onde será que estou errando?

Obs.: Quando abro o site, a barra de pedido é pequena no canto direito, quando clico no menu "**Peça**", a barra cresce para dar ligar ao formulário. Tanto a barra pequena quanto a grande devem sobrepor ao banner!

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque trata-se de um caso específico, dando um exemplo de site pessoal (que sabe lá até quando ficará online) para que fosse encontrado o problema. Da forma que a pergunta está atualmente dificilmente será relevante para outros usuários.

Comment: Concordo com o fechamento!  Porém, o site é empresarial.Já estava pronto! Apenas implementei um Banner no lugar de uma figura estática! Mas obrigado a quem pode ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua class .peca mude o z-index: 10; para z-index: 999;

Answer (score 0):

Você pode aplicar a regra abaixo.

```
div.peca {
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

Comment: o uso do !important é desnecessário